# What is HashMap memory usage in Java if it adds existing data

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, hashmap, space-complexity

Say I have two linked lists of same length.

```
class Node {
   int val;
   Node next;
}

List<Node> list1 = LinkedList<>(); // list1 has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... N
List<Node> list2 = LinkedList<>(); // list2 has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... N
```

I create a `HashMap` and map each element of list1 to list2

```
Map<Node, Node> map = new HashMap<Node, Node>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    map.put(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
}
```

The `HashMap` only inserts reference to existing data, it doesn't create any new Node. In term of memory usage, how much memory does the HashMap consume? In other words, if we talk about space complexity of this insertion (we are not counting the memory used by the `list1` and `list2` as extra memory), what is the space complexity? O(N) or O(1)?

Comment: How could it be O(1)? You said it yourself: The map needs to hold a reference to each element of the lists. How could it be O(1)?

Comment: The space complexity is `O(n)`, regardless of how many bytes it uses per element. The *complexity* only tells you, how it scales, and well, storing twice the number of elements will need roughly consume twice the memory. That’s a linear dependency, also known as `O(n)`. Besides that, there is no relationship between the map and the `LinkedList`, further, a `Node` class have a `next` reference suggests some kind of linked list that is also unrelated to the `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

A HashMap has to keep a reference to each key and each value it has. In practice, it would usually take up a bit more due to the internal data structures needed to implement the map, but it's negligible compared to the references to the keys and values. To make a long story short - a HashMap has an O(n) space complexity.

Comment: It doesn’t matter, how much more a `HashMap` node takes, it’s still `O(n)`, a linear dependency between size and space, the same way `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` have `O(n)` space complexity, despite the latter takes about six time the space of the former…